# Having an issue with t-sql and case statement with and/where clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
SELECT 3 AS LoggedIn, 83 AS MessageID, Data AS DistID, 1 AS StatusID
    , 0 AS Important
    , CASE WHEN (dd.SponsorID = 3) THEN 0 ELSE d.ReceiveUplineMessages END AS Test
    , dd.SponsorID 
FROM msg_SplitVar(',', @MessageList) sv
INNER JOIN Distributor d 
    ON d.DistID = sv.Data
INNER JOIN DistributorDetail dd 
    ON dd.DistID = sv.Data
WHERE Data NOT IN (SELECT DistID FROM MessageBlockList WHERE BlockedID = 3)
    AND Test = 0
```

I have a field set in the distributor table ReceiveUplineMessages.  This can be set to 0 or 1.
If they set this to 0 I only want to send them a message if it is from their sponsor (logged in)

I have the case statement working, but I'm having trouble with the `AND` clause.

The `splitVar` function just takes a string based array `'3,4,5,6,7'` and splits the data out to individual rows for an insert statement.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong in the AND clause?  I only want them to show up if `ReceiveUplineMessages` is a `0`.

Comment: Are you receiving an error?, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Error: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try not using your `Test` alias in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 3 AS LoggedIn, 83 AS MessageID, Data AS DistID, 1 AS StatusID
    , 0 AS Important
    , CASE WHEN (dd.SponsorID = 3) THEN 0 ELSE d.ReceiveUplineMessages END AS Test
    , dd.SponsorID 
FROM msg_SplitVar(',', @MessageList) sv
INNER JOIN Distributor d 
    ON d.DistID = sv.Data
INNER JOIN DistributorDetail dd 
    ON dd.DistID = sv.Data
WHERE Data NOT IN (SELECT DistID FROM MessageBlockList WHERE BlockedID = 3)
    AND (CASE WHEN (dd.SponsorID = 3) THEN 0 ELSE d.ReceiveUplineMessages END) = 0
```

or wrap your statement in another `SELECT` to use your Test in the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT t.*    
FROM
(
    SELECT 3 AS LoggedIn, 83 AS MessageID, Data AS DistID, 1 AS StatusID
        , 0 AS Important
        , CASE WHEN (dd.SponsorID = 3) THEN 0 ELSE d.ReceiveUplineMessages END AS Test
        , dd.SponsorID 
    FROM msg_SplitVar(',', @MessageList) sv
    INNER JOIN Distributor d 
        ON d.DistID = sv.Data
    INNER JOIN DistributorDetail dd 
        ON dd.DistID = sv.Data
    WHERE Data NOT IN (SELECT DistID FROM MessageBlockList WHERE BlockedID = 3)
) t
WHERE t.Test = 0
```

Comment: I used your first example and it worked perfectly, thank you.